# Can bower install from multiple bower.json files in a single project?

Tags: bower

Say I have my project set up like so:

```
/my-app
    bower.json
    /bower_components
    /vendor
        /package1
            bower.json
        /package2
            bower.json
```

Is it possible for me to configure bower (via .bowerrc, grunt or otherwise) to look at all the bower.json files and install all dependencies into `/my-app/bower_components`.

In other words can bower merge `/my-app/bower.json`, `/my-app/vendor/package1/bower.json` and `/my-app/vendor/package2/bower.json`.

If this is possible, is it possible to do automatically, i.e not have to provide specific paths to the package's bower.json files.

Comment: I did this way:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399841/merging-two-bower-json-files-with-similar-attributes-merging-two-json-files-wit?noredirect=1#comment48887545_30399841

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for a solution too; at the moment I have this simple shell script:

```
find packages plugins ! -path "packages/*/bower_components/*" ! -path "plugins/*/bower_components/*" -type f -name "bower.json" | while read file; do
  printf "Processing file '$file'\n"
  cd ./$(dirname $file)
  bower update
  cd -
done
```

It iterates through `bower.json` files located in `./packages` and `./plugins` and executes them. After that you have a `bower_components` folder for each package or plugin found. You need a second script (or build tool like Grunt or Gulp) to copy all assets from the packages/plugins to your public root assets folder.

Comment: Yeah, seems like a sensible approach - I can't imagine it handles dependencies though, right? i.e if two separate bower.json request conflicting versions etc.